# Android 'repo' documentation available?

Tags: android, repository, android-source

The only documentation about googles 'repo' tool for android repository management was:

https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/opensource/download/using-repo

This was less than nothing: the available help is the same as when typing:

> repo help

Does anyone know another source of documentation?

I explicitly want to know how to revert local changes:
-of a git repository that is part of the 'repo'
-of the repo '/manifest' folder or other 'repo' changes

Answer (score 9):

Documentation about `repo` is a bit hard to come about, as you have discovered.

In addition to your link, the `repo help <subject>` commands are very useful. E.g. `repo help manifest` and `repo help sync` are quite well described.

Also if you look in your `.repo/repo/docs/manifest-format.txt` there are very decent description of the manifest system used by the Android repo program.

If you discover additional resources of information on `repo` I would be very interested in hearing about it. :)

Comment: You can see `manifest-format.txt` on the web at http://code.google.com/p/git-repo/source/browse/docs/manifest-format.txt?r=bca94fd1b0

Comment: That's the same output that "repo help manifest" will give you.