# What is the manifest format of the Android repo tool?

Tags: documentation, manifest, file-format, repository, manual

I've used the [`repo`](http://code.google.com/p/git-repo/) command line for a new project based on many Git repositories. What is the manifest format? I haven't found any specification/manual/documentation about it.

For example this is a simplified `default.xml`

```
<manifest>
  <remote  name="aosp" fetch="https://android.googlesource.com" review="android-review.googlesource.com"/>
  <remote  name="github" fetch=".." review="review.cyanogenmod.org"/>
  <remote  name="private" fetch="ssh://git@github.com"/>
  <default revision="refs/tags/1.3-1" remote="github" sync-c="true" sync-j="4"/>
  <project path="build" name="CyanogenMod/android_build">
    <copyfile src="core/root.mk" dest="Makefile"/>
  </project>
  <project path="android" name="CyanogenMod/android"/>
  <project path="abi/cpp" name="CyanogenMod/android_abi_cpp"/>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally found some documentations, I post them here to be useful for others ;)

1. Enter the command `repo help manifest` (from [Edward Falk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/338479)'s comment)
2. Edit the file `.repo/repo/docs/manifest-format.txt` (from [Bjarke Freund-Hansen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7023059/938111))
3. Go to https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/+/master/docs/manifest-format.txt (from [David Fraser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/120398)'s comment)

Comment: Note: the manifest-format.txt link in the above answer has since been renamed to this: https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/+/master/docs/manifest-format.md

Answer (score 1):

I found this question looking for `copyfile` tag and after searching into the source code I discovered this in `repo/manifest_xml.py`

```py
def _ParseCopyFile(self, project, node):
  src = self._reqatt(node, 'src')
  dest = self._reqatt(node, 'dest')
  if not self.IsMirror:
    # src is project relative;
    # dest is relative to the top of the tree
    project.AddCopyFile(src, dest, os.path.join(self.topdir, dest))
```

so `<copyfile>` copies a file from the given project into the file as described in the `dest` attribute (but relative to the top of the tree).

Comment: Does it copy a directory?  i.e if src=gradle (that gradle dir has gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties and .jar), dest=gradle, would the whole gradle dir and contents be copied over recursively like "cp -r"?

Comment: Way late to answer winwin's question, but just in case anyone else ends up here, here's where the actual copy takes place:

https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/+/master/project.py#232
(which calls `shutil.copy(src, dest)`, see also: https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy)

**TL;DR - copyfile copies a file, not a directory; delegates to shutil.copy**